# Indent your code according to Fibonacci

Tags: code-golf, string, fibonacci, subsequence

Okay, so I saw this in a meme and decided it'd be the perfect code golf challenge:

I prefer to increase the side of my indents according to the Fibonacci sequence:

```
class Kls
 def method
  t = Time.now
  if t.hour >= 12
    puts "It's afternoon"
    if t.hour == 18
       puts "It's time for your meal of:"
       %w(bread sausage brocolli milk).each do |food|
            "Some #{food}"
       end
    end
  else
    puts "It's not afternoon"
  end
 end
end
```

This means each line is indented by the sum of the spaces indented in the previous indentation-level. The first indention-level is indented by one space, then subsequent indention-levels are indented by 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, etc ***additional*** spaces.

### The challenge

Given a multi-line string with multiples of 2 spaces as indentation, convert it to a Fibonacci indented multi-line string instead.
This means every line with 0 indented spaces will remain 0 spaces; every line with 2 indented spaces will become 1 instead (sum of the first two Fibonacci numbers `0+1 = 1`); every line with 4 indented spaces will becomes 2 instead (sum of the first three Fibonacci numbers `0+1+1 = 2`); etc. So the number of indentations can be calculated as follows:

- Get the current amount of leading spaces (guaranteed to be a multiple of 2, so `[0,2,4,6,8,...]`)
- Divide this by 2, so we have our 0-indexed numbers (let's call it `n`)
- Get the first `[0,n]` (0-indexed) Fibonacci numbers
- Sum that sub-sequence together, and use that amount of leading spaces instead in the output

For example, for the output above, the input would have been:

```
class Kls
  def method
    t = Time.now
    if t.hour >= 12
      puts "It's afternoon"
      if t.hour == 18
        puts "It's time for your meal of:"
        %w(bread sausage brocolli milk).each do |food|
          "Some #{food}"
        end
      end
    else
      puts "It's not afternoon"
    end
  end 
end
```

If we take a look at the line containing `"Some #{food}"`:

In the input it has 10 amount of leading spaces, so `n` will be `10/2 = 5`. The first `[0,5]` Fibonacci numbers are: `[0,1,1,2,3,5]`. When we take the sum of that list (`0+1+1+2+3+5`) the new amount of leading spaces in the output would be 12.

The amount of indented spaces in the output for every 2 indented spaces in the input will be `[0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20, 33, 54, 88, ...]` [A000071 on oeis.org](http://oeis.org/A000071) (except for the first 0).

### Challenge rules:

- The space-indentation of the input is guaranteed to be multiples of 2 (`[0,2,4,6,8,...]`)
- The input is guaranteed to not contain more than 1 consecutive space elsewhere (except for the leading indentation of course)
- Use whatever language you like
- Please include a link to an online interpreter
- Input should be a multi-line string (so no, string-lists/arrays aren't allowed)
- Output should also be a multi-line string (either printed or returned as string)
- Your method should work for deeper-indented Fibonacci indented multi-line strings than the example
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to do it in the fewest bytes possible.

### Additional test cases:

Input:

```
this
  is
    one
      of
        the
          tests
            !
```

Output:

```
this
 is
  one
    of
       the
            tests
                    !
```

Input:

```
      And
  how
               about
        this ?
```

Output:

```
    And
 how
                                 about
       this ?
```

Input:

```
                    20 spaces?
```

Output:

```
                                                                                                                                               20 spaces?
```

Comment: What if there's 2 or more spaces in the code that aren't part of the indentation?

Comment: @AJFaraday I took the liberty of editing your challenge so it can be re-opened. The challenge in general is a nice idea and I personally like it; it was just not properly explained. If you see anything incorrect in what I've edited, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>22</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
|εDgsðÛ©g-;LÅfOð*®J}»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZY/PSsNAEMbveYqPiPgHDFYQRIknL/4BD/oCm@xsEtzsyO6GIqZHn8In8CK9ePKW3H2ldFtLS9vLx8w332@GOT0X2YiGof37uSlcP@0/u6/i5Oqh/1CP/fS4@76bdL/DkGvhHO61iwBJCjX5kmVoAI8Uz1VNieHxwqgUfFJyY3GdYnS28IDXxjvEt/7AQShP1jCbeDlbE2kgLpbuBuPDBSi2eJvHahIarC7jVXR/fJhZEhJONE4UhMxyzlpXqCv9cpSQyEtIRquYZbvCgPiJw@a997k/We8jI6PNirSj3V8M@@1//oGgiILMAA)

**21 bytes alternative using the formula \$Fib(\frac{n}{2}+2)-1\$ instead of \$\sum_{i=1}^{i=\frac{n}{2}}{Fib(i)}\$ :**
<sup>(Credit to [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171059/52210) for this formula.)</sup>

```
|εDgsðÛ©g-;ÌÅf<ð*®J}»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZY89TsNAEIV7n@LJCPEjYREkJASYigYo4QJr76xtZe1Bu2tFCKek4wacgAaloaLz9lzJ2YQoUULzNPPmfTOa03ORjWgYut/v28L6mf/oP4uTK//u39S1nx33X/fT/mcYci2sxYO2ESBJoSZXsgwN4JDiqaopaXiyNCoFl5TcGtykGJ0tPeC5dRbxnTuwEMqRaZibeDXbEGkgLlbuFuPCBSg2eFnEahIarC7jdXR/cpgZEhJWtFYUhMxwzlpXqCs9PkpI5CUko1PMsltjQPzIYfPe68KfbvZRI6PtirSl/7807Hb/@QOCIgoyBw)

**Explanation:**

```python
|                        # Take the input split by newlines
 ε                  }    # Map each line to:
  Dg                     #  Duplicate the line and take its length
    s                    #  Swap so the duplicated line is at the top of the stack again
     ðÛ                  #  Remove all leading spaces
       ©                 #  Store the result in the register (without popping)
        g                #  Take its length as well
         -               #  Subtract both lengths from each other
          ;              #  Halve it, because they are multiples of 2 indented spaces
           L             #  Create a list in the range [1, n]
            Åf           #  Get the i'th Fibonacci number for each
              O          #  And sum them together
               ð*        #  Have that many space characters
                 ®J      #  And join them with the saved string from the register
                    »    # And finally print the mapped list with new-lines
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
Ỵµ=⁶i0‘H‘ÆḞ’⁶ẋ;t⁶$)Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@/TsMwEIf3PMVPAUS7RMCEQGEGMcLC6MZnYnB8KHZUVRSpLCy8ACw8BSAEGzxJ8iLG/aNWhcFn33f3nXVXZMwohPbr9fst7@7f9U43eTqO5@eh/XjpJs@RtZ@Phz7em/2LEEJhhHM4NS4BJClU5EuWMQE8cpzrijLLwxnQCj4rualxlGN3b8aAm8Y7pCd@20EoT7VltumitjLyaOwv6Jrj4w9QXGM0batIGLA6SJetW8PeoCYh4UTjxCVhUHPBxmhU2lz3MxJFCckYK2Y5XmpAesZx8sbtlN@t5pGVyfqLjKP/u1j2f/eZCzEiieEX)

---

## Explanation

Let \$x\$ be the 1-indexing index of the first non-whitespace character (\$1,3,5,7,\dots\$).

Then the new indent is

$$F_{(x+1)/2+1}-1$$

where \$F\$ is the Fibonacci function.

Comment: Save 1 from both with `Ỵµ...)Y`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>111</s> <s>109</s> <s>100</s> 95 bytes

```python
g=lambda n:n<1or g(n-2)+g(n-4)
def f(I):
 for l in I:L=l.lstrip();print~-g(len(l)-len(L))*' '+L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDLTsMwELznK0ZGKDZVI7XigALhXtEbHLm4tZ1aON7IdlVVFH49OKVqVbjsY3ZnVrP9Pm3Iz4ehbZzsVkrC1/5pRgEt99O5mIzpXhRKGxi@EHUBk4cO1mNRLxtXuZiC7bl47IP16Xvacqc9d2I6pqUQdyXKyXIwnDG2djJGvLhYAKNip/N1lRsgocGb7XTlaXcErEGqNrQNeG4wmx8xoN@mCLZIZYQ0SQdP5NlpdmE0mfFwQq84KV84GtiPa52WDmRqdl693fFV0FIhym2UrcYq0Jqcs@is@xCVlusNFOFgiNThTAPYK2Xlm88R/7roaa@K60q7qP978ZT@@vkl5Igih/y8KvbOJl6@@1KI4Qc)

---

Saved:

- -5 bytes, thanks to ovs.

Comment: g can be `g=lambda n:n<1or g(n-2)+g(n-4)`.

Comment: and you can use `strip` instead of `lstrip` as trailing whitespace is insignificant.

Comment: @ovs But it would affect `len(l)-len(L)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 23 bytes

```
mȯF+M(R' !∫Θİf→½L)↕=' ¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@xSgNBEIb7PMVvRC5BONBKhLMMiNqoZZrN7ax3ZHdHdvcIYmyDtSD4DhZa2dkECysf4l7k3IshGmIxw8w/8/3DFJUfN435fBnsnvXOE2zV989fTx@vqp49zN9P@/XsMUswf2uaJtfCe5xo3wEkKRgKBcvYAAEZLktDqeXJQigVQlpw5XCUYW9/oQHXVfAYdo9D4iFUIGeZ7bC7nP4yWWQOluo6FeIRKHa4afcMCQ1WhysLYGfSGzkSEl5UXlwRRo5z1rqEKfW4n5LIC0jGVDHL6QpDPHDB0Xv7th3c/XEkKzvrFWlP/3xkOWx89YO0OcY3)

#### Explanation

```
m(F+M(R' !∫Θİf→½L)↕=' )¶  -- full program
                       ¶  -- lines
m(                    )   -- map
                  ↕='     -- | split on first non-space
    M(           )        -- | with the spaces
                L         -- | | length
               ½          -- | | halve
              →           -- | | increment
            İf            -- | | Fibonacci numbers: [1,1,2,3,5..]
           Θ              -- | | prepend 0: [0,1,1,2,3,5..]
          ∫               -- | | cumulative sums: [0,1,2,4,7,12..]
         !                -- | | 1-based index
      R'                  -- | | replicate that many spaces
  F+                      -- | join
```

Comment: This answer appears to have three levels of indent with only 1 space, then continuing in Fibonacci.

Comment: I had the same mistake at first. Instead of having the indexed Fibonacci amount of spaces in the result, it's actually the sum of the first `[1,n]` amount of Fibonacci numbers. So instead of `[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...]` indented spaces, it's `(sum_each([0,[0,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,1,2],[0,1,1,2,3],[0,1,1,2,3,5],[0,1,1,2,3,5,8],...])` -> `[0,1,2,4,7,12,20,...]` indented spaces instead.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: I was able to fix it w/o additional bytes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 37 bytes

```
m`^
 	 	
+`( +	)( +)	  
$2$1$1
 	 *
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9BT8MwDIXPza94KkVbmVSpOyGk7o44whktaxwakcQoSTUhxm8v6Zg2DS5P9rO/ZzlQMl5Ok9u@ChQoxGq7xKqos9QFIKp11VbtPLorxDT1VsaIJxsFoEjDURpY5QZI6PBiHDWe90fDaKRm4DFg06FdHz3gY0wR5WNaREidKHhmX55mF6LLxP3JvWJSvgDNAZ/zmiNpwfqhPK/e7pe7QFIhyjHKN8IucM/WGjhj3@uGZD9AMQ6aWR3OGFA@c06@@Zr970seeSWuK7KR/v/iOf395xfICpHlBw) Warning: Lots of white space. Explanation:

```
m`^
```

Prefix each line with space tab space tab. These keep track of the previous and current Fibonacci number.

```
+`( +   )( +)     
$2$1$1
```

For each two spaces of the original indentation, compute the next Fibonacci number by summing the previous two.

```
 	 *
```

Subtract 1 from the result and delete the previous Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt v2.0a0, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
r/^ +/m@ÓMgXÊz ÄÄ)ç
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ci9eICsvbUDTTWdYynogxMQp5w==&input=ImNsYXNzIEtscwogIGRlZiBtZXRob2QKICAgIHQgPSBUaW1lLm5vdwogICAgaWYgdC5ob3VyID49IDEyCiAgICAgIHB1dHMgYEl0J3MgYWZ0ZXJub29uYAogICAgICBpZiB0LmhvdXIgPT0gMTgKICAgICAgICBwdXRzIGBJdCdzIHRpbWUgZm9yIHlvdXIgbWVhbCBvZjpgCiAgICAgICAgJXcoYnJlYWQgc2F1c2FnZSBicm9jb2xsaSBtaWxrKS5lYWNoIGRvIHxmb29kfAogICAgICAgICAgYFNvbWUgI3tmb29kfWAKICAgICAgICBlbmQKICAgICAgZW5kCiAgICBlbHNlCiAgICAgIHB1dHMgYEl0J3Mgbm90IGFmdGVybm9vbmAKICAgIGVuZAogIGVuZCAKZW5kIg==)

---

### Explanation

```
r                        :Replace
 /^ +/m                  :Global, multiline regular expression matching one or more spaces at the start of each line
       _                 :Pass each match through a function
        Ê                :  Length
         z               :  (Floor) divide by 2
           õ             :  Range [0,result]
              @          :  Map each X
               MgX       :    Xth Fibonacci number
                  Ã      :  End mapping
             x           :  Reduce by addition
                   ç     :  Repeat <space> that many times
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ỵµwt©⁶$HÆḞ€⁶ẋ;®)Y
```

A full program which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xTsMwEIb3PMWvAIIukWBCoDCDGGFhdOMzCTg@ZDuKKsoAAwvvwI6EmAAh2MKTpC9i3FK1Kiynu//@7z/dBWk9CqH/eu3eWt89TW7f1w@/7/uPx8ndcxz6z4f97mVwFkIotHAOx9olgCSFmnzJMg6AR47TqqbMcDsTKgWfldxYHOTY3plpwFXjHdIjv@kglCdrmE063y2JPBK7c3WF8fECFFuMpraahAarvXRh3Wi3hpaEhBONE@eEoeWCta5QV/pykJEoSkjGWDHL8QID0hOOyWvXU/1mmUdGJqsdaUf/fzHs//7zC8SKJJYf)**

#### How?

The indentations required for a line of the output is \$Fib(\frac{s}{2}+2)-1\$ where \$s\$ is the number of spaces in the line of the input, and:

$$Fib(\frac{s}{2}+2)-1=\sum_{i=1}^{i=\frac{s}{2}}{Fib(i)}$$

<sup>(\$i\$ could also start at \$0\$ since \$Fib(0)=0\$)</sup>

```
Ỵµwt©⁶$HÆḞ€⁶ẋ;®)Y - Main Link: list of characters
Ỵ                 - split at newlines
 µ             )  - for each line:
      $           -   last 2 links as a monad:
     ⁶            -     literal space character
   t              -     trim from both sides
    ©             -     (copy to register)
  w               -   first index of that substring in the line
       H          -   halve (this is (s+1)/2)
        ÆḞ€       -   Fibonacci of €ach (using an implicit range [1,2,...,s/2]
                  -                      where the (s+1)/2 is floored to s/2)
           ⁶      -   literal space character
            ẋ     -   repeat (vectorises) (e.g. [1,1,2,3,5] -> [[' '],[' '],[' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']]
              ®   -   recall from register
             ;    -   concatenate
                Y - join with newline characters 
                  - implicit print
                  -  ...smashes, so e.g. [[' '],[' '],[' ',' '],['x']] is just "    x"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 11, 150 bytes

```java
s->{for(var l:s.split("\n"))System.out.println(" ".repeat(f(l.length()-(l=l.stripLeading()).length())-1)+l);};int f(int n){return n<1?1:f(n-2)+f(n-4);}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##pVRdT9swFH3frzjLNGGLNlC0h4muoD1sEvtgD/BGmeQmDjE4dhU7IFT627vrOKGp1j0tD3Z8z/06J765F49ifJ8/bDItnMNPoczqDaCMl3UhMonLcAQercqRsStfK3MHx6dkXb@h5RIGM2zc@GxV2Jo9ihr61KVuqZVnydwknF89Oy@r1DY@XVK414bVcikF4UhGBdOplubOl4yPmZ45KrH8IUVOhb4wzfkryscTfqj5dD2lJChYWA1f1dI3tYH5NDmfnBbMjE/4Ydg@kOeGOlw2C60yOC88bS2Rimh2XG5uIXjk6KWjlqIQ37WbGyCXBSrpS5uHE7kQ12tVydTYp2hRBXxa2qbG2QyTk2gMRb3DPLnwBw6iIDGNtWae9PA2akZRH3vzbpynQiBR8RwcKyk0bHG6TQK8f2KLmqSCE40TdxKL2mZWa4VK6QeeSpGVyC1eCmvzl20cqMSVpezvVgFZD3NKk/eH11epndzHzFj/N7suqt1oQdJell5eX6pW2bgC1rxmtsW2C1/KYbsh1g0NwNvdvNH4OdYu@68zeMSCLuCwgHI435dj9zk5hlvSILjOt730w7vUhnZzoQyp090mI5/acWI8NWnGIjQNSAvvGYpk/K9nUProCN9oZjGZkITmwJOAuL74hWfpR3A28pJVowU1hthXOpwpxiEcdqcsunFK3w/4HjgYO27dyJEhpUnWJM9XVQcFf@MwGSX/2273dyBV2l67YwRHwbptdAcLDQUcorKN8bvNhu8R3Vh4zUpR30S/W96zoB/WcTIKPCOB9eYP) (NOTE: Both `String.repeat(int)` and `String.stripLeading()` are emulated as `repeat(String,int)` and `stripLeadingE(String)` respectively, because Java 11 isn't on TIO yet.)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                   // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(var l:s.split("\n"))
                       //  Loop over the lines of the input:
    System.out.println(//   Print with trailing new-line:
      " ".repeat(      //    Repeat a space this many times:
           f(          //     Call the separated (recursive) method `f` with the parameter:
             l.length()//      The length of the line,
             -(l=l.stripLeading()).length()
                       //      minus the length of the line without leading spaces
           )-1         //     minus 1
      )+l);};          //    And append the line without leading spaces

int f(int n){          // Separated method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  return n<1?          //  If the input is 0 or lower:
          1            //   Return 1
         :             //  Else:
          f(n-2)+f(n-4);}
                       //   Return a recursive call to `n-2` plus a recursive call to `n-4`
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>87</s> 81 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/^ */gm,s=>" ".repeat((g=(n,a=b=1)=>n?g(n-2,b,b+=a):b-1)(s.length)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BTsMwDIbve4pfRYgEuk7bCW1KOSOOcEZLW6ctpPGUZGyI8eylG9OmwcWyP/uz5Tf9oUPp21UcO66oN6rfqnybeVpZXZKYvOJ2UndpUHmCZI9JRyFqJVyqVaGmUuXuoRZuPEuLtLhTWs6L8VSKkFlydWyklP2iZBfYUma5FkYsS6tDwJMNI6Aig45iw9VQABEKL21HmePNAbQGMWt47ZErTGcHBqzWMSB5jDcB2kTyjtklx97ZUINxf6QXThwuwLDH536sI23BZp6cRq83ovCkKwS9DromFJ5LtrZF19p3mZEuG1SMnWGudicNSJ552Hz1teff533kqtFlRjbQ/18cx7///ApDxGgISykX/Q8)

### For small indent levels (up to 15), 61 bytes using approximation:

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/^ */gm,s=>" ".repeat(1.272**s.length*1.171-.5))
```

Use `1.27202 ** s.length * 1.17082 - .5` for indents up to 21 levels

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 62 bytes

```perl6
*.trans(/[\n|^]' '+/=>{"\n"~' 'x(1,1,*+*...*)[$/.ords/2+1]-1})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxdC4IwFIbv/RWnEemmbayLbsKi36EGhhOF2sKzKOnjr69hIXYuznmew8t7Ud1p7c49LGpIwTFuu1JjJLJcPw9FCGEs0u2D5Jq8vdwjmciExYxzzmg2F9x0FYpVLIulfFG3CbDsoY6IbVoMAIYFYLQarqf6BwC2USN7U2hx4gAzQse672evK59ozO0v56c8mqudFLcIO0LdBw)